# Select the next node of the selected node in PHP DOM?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

So far I'm working on a HTML file like this

```
<div name="node"></div>
<div></div>
<div name="node"></div>
<div></div>
<div name="node"></div>
<div></div>
```

I want to select the next node of every "div" which has its name equal to "node" and I try :

```
$dom = new DOMdocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$els = $xpath->query("//div[@name='node']");

$j = 0;

foreach($els as $el)
{
    if($el->next_sibling()) $j++;
}

echo $j;
```

But I just get an error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::next_sibling()

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my script please?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The error is quite clear: there is no method `DOMElement::next_sibling()`. Read the [documentation for `DOMElement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) and it's parent class [`DOMNode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php). You are thinking of the *property* `DOMNode::nextSibling`.

However, `nextSibling` gets the next *node*, not the next *element*. (There is no DOM method or property that gets the next element. You need to keep using `nextSibling` and checking `nodeType` until you hit another element.) Your question says you want the next node but I think you may actually want the next element (the empty `<div>`). This is actually quite easy to do with XPath, so why don't you do that instead?

To get it immediately:

```
$els = $xpath->query("//div[@name='node']/following-sibling::*[1]");
```

To get it when you already have a `<div name="node">`:

```
$nextelement = $xpath->query("following-sibling::*[1]", $currentdiv);
```

Comment: That's right, I want to get the next element but just miss used `nextSibling`. Thank you so much for your nice explanation the script now work fine as expected!

Answer (score 6):

There's is not function called next_sibling() in DOM. You should use the property nextSibling defined in DOMNode (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php).

```
foreach($els as $el)
{
    if($el->nextSibling) $j++;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know `php` but this `xpath` gets them:

```
//div[@name="node"]/following-sibling::*[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring text nodes (hopefully, not tested)

```
foreach($els as $el){
  $next = $el->nextSibling;
  while($next){
    if($next->nodeType!==3){
       $j++;
       break;
    }
    $next = $next->nextSibling;
  }
}
```

As a function

```
function nextElement($node, $name=null){
    if(!$node){
        return null;
    }
    $next = $node->nextSibling;
    if(!$next){
        return null;
    }
    if($next->nodeType === 3){
        return self::nextElement($next, $name);
    }
    if($name && $next->nodeName !== $name){
        return null;
    }
    return $next;
}
```

Usage

```
foreach($els as $el)
{
    if(nextElement($el,'div')) $j++;
}
```