# Get following node in DOM

Tags: php, xpath

I'm attempting to get the next node `<p>` after locating an `<h4>` with a value of `My Title`. Nothing seems to come back for it based on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549300/679449).

```
$load_html = <<<LOAD_HTML
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h4><span><strong>My Title</strong></span></h4>
<p><strong>FIND ME<br />
   </strong>
</p>
LOAD_HTML;

@$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($load_html);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

$xp_nodes = $xpath->query("//h4/span/strong[text() = 'My Title']/following-sibling::*[1]");

foreach($xp_nodes as $xp_node) {
    echo $xp_node->nodeValue;
}
```

I am trying to get to `FIND ME`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want following-sibling of `h4`, but in your Xpath you ask sibling of `strong`.

Correct Xpath is

```
//h4[span/strong[text() = 'My Title']]/following-sibling::*[1]
```