# Php Html Parser "find next"

Tags: php, jquery, dom

Im using paquettg/php-html-parser to parse html jquery style in php.

I fail to find the function similiar to jquery's next(). For instance the equivalent to next("p") in below jquery:

`var string=$("span#a").parent().next("p").text();`

Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for in PHP is the [DOMElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) class. Specifically, I think you're looking for the [DOMNode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nextsibling) method.

This method finds the node immediately following this node. If there is no such node, this returns NULL.

I might recommend looking at this ticket for an example of how you can implement this method to accomplish your task [Select the next node of the selected node in PHP DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549300/select-the-next-node-of-the-selected-node-in-php-dom)